# Are cartesian (cross) joins with where statement still slower than inner joins?

Tags: sql

Compare these two queries:

```
select b.prod_name, b.prod_category, a.transaction_amt, a.transaction_dt
  from transactions a, prod_xref b
where a.prod_id = b.id
```

VS.

```
select b.prod_name, b.prod_category, a.transaction_amt, a.transaction_dt
  from transactions a 
  inner join b.prod_xref b on a.prod_id = b.id
```

Is the first query still slower than the second?
What are the benefits / disadvantages of using a cartesian join vs an explicit join statement?

Comment: These queries are the same except the first uses the legacy join syntax

Comment: Here is something that might help: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 2):

Answering your question, "Cartesian" or "Cross" join are much slower than almost any joins.
The reason is that `CROSS` join multiply each row of t1 by each row of t2.

The example you provided **is not** a CROSS join;

It's the **old syntax of inner joins**, where 2 or more consecutive tables are given in `FROM` clause, comma separated.